Colab Enterprise Notebook Scheduler vs GCP Functions & Scheduler
I am trying to build data ingestion pipelines (ETL) using Google Cloud Platform
I have python scripts that downloads public data, uploads it to cloud storage, and performs transformation on this data and uploads it to BigQuery
These scripts have to be run on a schedule ( hourly & daily)
We are considering two options to achieve this goal:
Option 1:

create a pub/Sub topic
create a schedule in cloud scheduler that publishes messages to this pub/Sub topic
create a cloud function with the python code which subscribes to this pub/Sub topic and thus gets triggered whenever it receives a message from pub/sub

Option 2:

upload my python code to Colab notebooks enterprise
schedule a notebook run

Which of these two options is better overall?
Is there a comparison of cost, reliability & efficiency between the two methods?
Have tried both methods to build data ingestion pipelines and they work as expected

I have a better proposal:

Package your code in a container
Deploy your container on Cloud Run Jobs
Use Cloud Scheduler to invoke the Cloud Run Jobs

Here, some explanation on that proposal:

A container is today a universal way to package your code. Here I propose to run it on Cloud Run Jobs, but you could also deploy your container on a K8S cluster (GKE for instance), on a compute engine, on any other service that accepts containers.
Cloud Run Job is perfectly designed to run efficiently at scale, in serverless mode. It's the next gen of Cloud Functions (Cloud Functions gen2 backend is Cloud Run!); Jobs can run up to 7 days!
Cloud Scheduler is the perfect service for scheduling. Invoke the Cloud Run Jobs execution API, with OAuth security and a service account with the Cloud Run Invoker role.

